# How to make fade in and out transition of jQuery innerHTML change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following simple button that toggles the innerHTML text. I have been looking for a slow fade in and fade out transition for the change of innerHTML on click but haven't have a good luck doing that. Can you please help me out how I may achieve that?

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

```js
var Chg;
var Btn = document.getElementById("change");

$("#change").click(function() {
    Chg = !Chg;
    if (Chg) {
        Btn.innerHTML = "Toggled";
    } else {
        Btn.innerHTML = "Not Toggled";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="change">Not Toogled</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a potential solution, which may work depending on what effect you're going for.

```js
var Chg;

$("#change").click(function() {
    Chg = !Chg;
    var text;
    if (Chg) {
        text = "Toggled";
    } else {
        text = "Not Toggled";
    }
    $(this).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        this.innerHTML = text;
        $(this).fadeIn("fast");
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="change">Not Toggled</button>
```

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I have been looking for. Thanks a lot. I was wondering is there any way to control the speed of fadeIn or fadeOut?

Comment: Yes, that's what the `"slow"` parameter is for.  You can use `"slow"`, `"fast"`, or just pass the number of milliseconds you want (for example, `200`)

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your suggestion and lesion.  :) @snapjs

Comment: Exposing a global `var Chg` just for the purpose of storing a single button state is bad design. Your mindset should always be *Code Flexibility* - If eventually one day you change `#change` to `.change` (and multiple buttons) the JS should work regardlessly.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#change").on('click',function() {
    var $this=$(this);
    var x,x1;
    if($this.attr("data-Toggle")=="0"){
       x="span:first-child";
       x1="span:last-child";
       $this.attr("data-Toggle","1");
    }
    else{
       x="span:last-child";
       x1="span:first-child";
       $this.attr("data-Toggle","0");
    }
    $this.find(x).fadeToggle(500);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
     $this.find(x1).fadeToggle();
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
button{width:100px;height:20px;}
button span:last-child{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-Toggle="0" id="change">
<span>Not Toggled</span>
<span>Toggled</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Wow! This is even a better solution. Thanks a lot for this suggestion. It is beautiful.  :)